# How to map spark sql query result to object?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

As I know, MyBatis is very good. It can map jdbc result to a object.
For spark sql query result,  Is there any good way to map spark query result to object? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the result received from a Spark SQL query is a SchemaRDD, an entity on which you can execute all the operations granted on a standard RDD. Returning to your question, for the moment, the only way to map the query result to a class(and, consequently, an object) is manually with a classic map operation to manipulate the information stored inside the returned rows in your SchemaRDD.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this how to you would query a table, convert it to objects of your class `YourClass`, into `JavaRDD` then write it to a file.
Each line in the file would be constructed from  `YourClass.toString()`

```
DataFrame sqlQuery = sqlContext.sql("SELECT a,b,c FROM table");
JavaRDD<Triple> resultRows = sqlQuery.javaRDD().map(
        new Function<Row, YourClass>() {
            public YourClass call(Row row) {
                YourClass t = new YourClass(row.getString(0), row.getString(1), row.getString(2));
                return t;
            }
        });
resultRows.saveAsTextFile(outputFolderPath);
```